# Review bug on viewing edit history

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, navigation

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to Review, any section
2. Open a question/answer that already has editing history, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/676882)
3. Click `edited {date}`
4. Click `Return to Answer`

**Actual:**
Redirected to the question/answer itself, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184402/how-can-i-clear-rows-in-datagridview-with-c/12307547#12307547).

**Expected:**
Redirected to the review page.

Answer (score 4):

I am not particularly sure I expect the page to work like you describe. The browsers *Back* button does direct you to the previous page. This link links you to the answer, as it says itself. It doesn't mention the review page at all.

When you review and hit any link, you know you are going entirely out of the review queue and go back to the normal site with its normal behavior. If you want to go back to the review, just hit the browser's back button.